# What can one do when Robotium's Solo clickOnText "misses" the view it has found?

Tags: android, robotium

I have a list of products in my app. In that list activity, I create a strip along the right side of the window, a "alphabet picker string", like one sees in contact list applications.

It works great.

On an emulator, I can test it without problem. On an actual tablet, the test fails every time. It consistently clicks to the left of the target view, which means the list of products does not get updated to the intended selection.

I captured this info on both the emulator and the device, but I am not seeing an obvious (or obvious to me) source of the problem.

The picker view on the emulator (of a xxhdpi Nexus 5):

```
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getLeft = 49
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getRight = 101
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getTop = 955
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getBottom = 998
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getWidth = 52
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getHeight = 43
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getX = 49.0
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getY = 955.0
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker locationInWindow = [979, 1174]
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker locationOnScreen = [979, 1174]
```

on my device (an mdpi Samsung tablet):

```
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getLeft = 96
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getRight = 550
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getTop = 0
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getBottom = 85
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getWidth = 454
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getHeight = 85
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getX = 96.0
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker getY = 0.0
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker locationInWindow = [96, 513]
 I/System.out﹕ TEST: picker locationOnScreen = [96, 513]
```

Should I just expect that the Solo method, clickOnText, in inaccurate and cannot be relied on?

Answer (score 0):

please add a code.

I think you use method with position parameters which works great with your specific smartphone, but it failed on tablets, because your desired view has other position values.

Try to catch a view in more universal way, like by its text value.